# action формы не взаимодействует с сервлетом

Tags: java, html5, сервлеты

Начал изучать сервлеты, форма(с html страницы) не отправляет данные на указанный url, притом сам сервлет работает(проверял через postman).
Сервлет:

```
@WebServlet( value = "/security"
)

public class ValidationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private MainService service;
    public ValidationServlet(){
        service = new MainService();
    }

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    ValidationObject object =service.getUser(req.getParameter("login"),req.getParameter("password"));

    switch (object.getNumber()){
        case 0 -> resp.setStatus(403);
        default -> {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/classes/static/Profile.html").forward(req,resp);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Форма:

```html
          <form action="security" method="get">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="login">enter your email there</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" id="login" aria-describedby="emailHelpId" placeholder="">
                      <small id="emailHelpId" class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
                    </div>
        
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">enter your password here</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="">
                      </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Log in</button>       
            </form>
```

Расположение директорий:

[image: Расположение]

Comment: F12 в браузере, вкладка Network и смотрите, куда форма и что отправляет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я запускал статические страницы отдельно в директории, а не на сервере, решил, спасибо tym32167